# how to give a container div the height of the inner div

Tags: html, css

I have to dives 
container with class=d and it's background color red
and inner with class=d2 with a background color gray

as shown the the following pictures,

[image: div d]
[image: div d2]
and i want div d take the height of div d2 but i don't know how

this is the code

```
.d
{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;


}

.d2
{
    width:80%;
    height:auto;    
    float:left;
    background-color:Gray;

}
```

and if i put the height of div d "auto" the red color will "disappear"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need another div the style is clear:both like this then the height of d can set as auto

```
<style>
.d
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
}
.d2
{
    width:80%;
    height:auto;    
    float:left;
    background-color:Gray;
}
</style>
<div class="d">
    <div class="d2">
    type something here<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    something again the parent div's height will depend by this div
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.d` has a specified height (in your case, it does -- 100px) then you can set

```
.d2 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have d's height set:

```
.d
{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

set the height of d2 to either 100px or 100%:

```
.d2
{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;    
  float:left;
  background-color:Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `d2` height is larger than your `d` container the way I see it. I guess you don't want your container to have the same height as your `d2` if `d2` is smaller but if it is bigger your `d` container should still be large enough.

If this is the case change the `height` in your `d` to `min-height: 100px;`